# Give condition from value that have called

Tags: javascript

Hello i'd like to put condition for my code in javascript if the code has already called, so after the `_edg.source` it wont to called again:

```
for (var j in GexfJS.graph.edgeList) { 
    var _edg = GexfJS.graph.edgeList[j]
    if ( (_edg.target == _curra) && (_edg.source != _nodeIndex) && (_edg.target != _n)) {
        var _nod = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[_edg.source];

        if(_n != _nod){
            _str += '<li><div class="smallpill" style="background: ' + _nod.color.base +'"></div><a href="#" onmouseover="GexfJS.params.activeNode = ' + _edg.target + '" onclick="displayNode(' + _edg.target + ', true); return false;">' + _nod.label + 'b</a>' + ( GexfJS.params.showEdgeWeight && _edg.weight ? ' [' + _edg.weight + ']' : '') + '</li>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See if this helps for your next question http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use condition with an object and set the true value after the value has called, insert this code after the var `_nod`

```
check={};
if(check[_nod.label] != true){
......


}
check[_nod.label] = true;
```